# How can I extract text from another website using python and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

I would like to link some text that is under directors from for example from IMDb. I can see JavaScript is used in the inspect element, is it possible to list the movie names as a list in the output of python? Making the code read just that part of the  JavaScript from the website and then being able to use it without the need of writing the titles down. In addition, can it only note "movie titles" in years 2015 - 2015.

I am a beginner but this is a project to help reduce time when writing something.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) webdriver library for python. It allows you to automate the process of navigating around websites, and also has the ability to scrape text and other information from elememts. To start you off, your program might look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # you can include options like path
driver.get("imdb.com")
lis = driver.find_element_by_class_name('li') # getting list elements, for example
for li in lis:
    print(li.text)
```

Make sure you download BOTH the browser of your choice (i.e. the application) and the appropriate driver. For chrome, it would be [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/).

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful :)